# how to convert html to text without comment?

Tags: jquery

Suppose, I've this in the html:

```
<code><?php die(); ?></code>
```

Now, I wanted to get the result same `<?php die(); ?>` but it's getting along with html comment:

```
<!--?php die(); ?-->
```

---

```
$('code').text($('code').html());
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QsCsr/)

So, now how can I remove the `!--` and `--` from the text?

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to achieve, but under normal circumstances the two **NEVER MEET**. **THE SERVER CONVERTS ALL PHP INTO HTML and by the time it hits the client, where JS/jQuery is waiting ... the PHP is 'GONE'**

Comment: I'm not trying to make php work but display it as just text.

Comment: It would be helpful to state it clearly in your question so we are not left guessing. Your goal determines the kind of answer you get.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)**

```
<pre>&lt;?php die(); ?&gt;<pre>
```

Or

```
<code>&lt;?php die(); ?&gt;<code>
```

You **should** escape characters like `>,<,&`

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QsCsr/8/)**

*Hint : The code you posted in your Question(4spaces) - See how Stack Overflow does it by inspecting element.*

Comment: `<code>&lt;?php die();?&gt;<code>` Using `<code>` gave same output.cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
var c = $("code").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 8; //comment node
}).get(0).data;
//add '<' and '>', because they are replaced as part of comment by filter()
$("code").text("<" + c + ">"); //gives <?php die(); ?>
```

Updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QsCsr/12/)

Comment: I couldn't understand the way you are doing with .get(0).data specially data.